# I receive SSL CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when doing poetry install

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ssl, connection

I am trying to create a virtual environment and I was able to do in the past with poetry install. But now when trying to do a `poetry install`, I receive this message:

```
Max retries exceeded with url: /pypi/six/1.16.0/json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.9/requests/adapters.py:514 in send
      510│                 raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
      511│ 
      512│             if isinstance(e.reason, _SSLError):
      513│                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
    → 514│                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
      515│ 
      516│             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
      517│ 
      518│         except ClosedPoolError as e:
```

Answer (score 26):

what worked for me (MacOS)
go to Applications > Python folder > double click on "Install Certificates.command" file

Answer (score 8):

It seems like Python's requests library cannot find your certificates.

**Have you configured a custom repository with a self-signed certificate?**
If so I have not found a *great* solution to this problem.
In that case, please see whether you have set your CURL_CA_BUNDLE environment variable:

> $ echo $CURL_CA_BUNDLE

If this points to some custom location/self-signed certificate, requests is not able to use its standard certificate bundle.
You can unset it(might have side effects on services that uses it):

> export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=""

**If you have not configured any custom repository/certificates:**

You might be able to solve this by installing [certifi](https://pypi.org/project/certifi/)

Comment: The names are not consistent, you write about CURL_CA_BUNDLE but echo REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE. I was able to fix my problem by unsetting CURL_CA_BUNDLE!

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.7 when installed on MacOSX systems needs to run a script to install certificate dependencies on your system for python environment via bash.

```
#!/bin/sh

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 << "EOF"

# install_certifi.py
#
# sample script to install or update a set of default Root Certificates
# for the ssl module.  Uses the certificates provided by the certifi package:
#       https://pypi.org/project/certifi/

import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys

STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )

def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)

    print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
        "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])

    import certifi

    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
EOF
```

This is the contents of the bash script which installs certifi package ssl certs. It should also be located in your installed Python folder in Applications.

```
cd /Applications/Python\ 3.7/
./Install\ Certificates.command
```