# poetry installation on windows: ssl.SSLCertVerificationError ssl certificate verify failed

Tags: python, windows, ssl, python-poetry

The installation of poetry on Win 10 fails. I'm using python 3.10

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | py -
Retrieving Poetry metadata
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1276, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1322, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1271, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1031, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 969, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1448, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 940, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 919, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 516, in run
  File "<stdin>", line 775, in get_version
  File "<stdin>", line 836, in _get
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1391, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1351, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)>
```

There is a suggestion to run `Install Certificates.command`: [certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52805115/certificate-verify-failed-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)
But I can't find this file in the python location or anywhere else on my computer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69814872/ Here they suggest to go to the installation folder and run the "Install Certificates" file. That did the trick for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it by using pip (from powershell): `pip install poetry`